# Strange syntax error

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB, and I have the following problem:

I have the line:

```
[~, j] = min(matrix);
```

I don't understand what the `~` sign is for(I have to learn this code..) and the error is:

```
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

What can be the reason?

---

Another question, suppose I have got a `file.m` and inside of it I have the declaration:

```
methods (Static)
        function var = func(n, d)
```

How do I call this function with the 2 parameters from the command windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i dont understand whats for ~ sign

Discard first returning output, it is not going to be used.

> What can be the reason?

What version of Matlab do you use? This syntax has only been part of MATLAB since about R2009b or so.

> How do i call this function func with the 2 parameters from the command windows?

Yes, otherwise - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/support-variable-number-of-inputs.html

Comment: @Anton Than your Matlab is slightly old for this syntax, update it. Or you can use some variable instead of tilde, just remove it if you do not need it.